# Shutting down narrator on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, narrator

I don't know how I managed to get the narrator to start nagging me, but it is certainly nagging.
To make it clear - I know how to exit the narrator once it is working. The problem I am having is with it keep launching again and again.
Whenever I restart my windows, the narrator is working, and I have to shut it down. Whenever I return to my computer after a while, and have to enter my password again, the narrator is working again. Whenever I run something that required UAC, the narrator is working again.

How did I managed to get to this state? And how can I finally and completely stop this annoying narrator from launching again?

Comment: Have you tried to turn service off, or reconfigure it in msconfig ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=13455) link with a suggestion on where to look for the elusive checkbox to uncheck. After clearing it, I no longer have the original problem.

---EDIT---

Copying the solution from the link, as @Karen suggested in the comments:
go to Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center -> Explore all Settings -> Use the computer without a display. Uncheck the checkbox by Turn on Narrator and click Save.

Comment: Since the link may die you should also include the solution here for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable Narrator.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open *Ease of Access Center*.
3. Click *Change administrative settings* in the left pane.
4. Uncheck *Apply all settings to the logon desktop*.

Comment: I have found a different solution in another link that fixed my problem, and I do not have a `Change administrative settings` in the left pane of the `Ease of Access Center`. I do have `Change sign-in settings`, and it is all cleared in there at the moment... However, it might be the result of applying the other solution I've found earlier. Thanks for the tip. I hope it helps someone else.